# Deploy Laravel to AWS with DNS and DB credentials (url, username/password) from windows using Putty

Tags: mysql, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, putty

As a *freelancer*, I've been provided with following details to deploy the application to their sever.

**Server DNS**: xxx-x-xx-xxx-x.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
**DB**: xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.eu-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com
**user**: xxxxxxxxxx
**password**: xxxxxxxxxx

I've already read the **putty** and **laravel** docs regarding this but still couldn't figure out a way to deploy the laravel application from **localhost** (on **windows**) to the **AWS** with the above provided details. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: There are many, many ways to deploy something like Laravel. Ask your client for more info (preferably documentation) on how it's been deployed in the past.

Comment: Can you provide more details?
The server is already running a web server, is php installed, firewalls are configured, do you have ssh access?

Comment: @Mirdrack this is all I got from the client and it's the first time i'm facing a problem like this and not sure how to work around with this because previous clients provided me the server (hosting) credentials and it was much easier to deploy the app but now with this I don't even know what to ask. I'll be really grateful if you could help me out with this, thanks!

Comment: You didn't answer the questions
You need to provide more details about the environment where you are trying to deploy

Answer (score 0):

There is not nearly enough information provided for you to deploy anything. You have DNS information, so you can test that the server is available - but that's about all you can do.

Your client should have some sort of deployment process (even if it is manual). Ask them about their deployment process.

A manual process consists of at least some sort of files access to the server. Without anyway of accessing the file system, you can't place an files on the server. And if you can't place files on the server you can't "deploy" anything directly.

They are using AWS. AWS has several options for delivering code to a server indirectly. Read up on deployment strategies available in AWS for EC2 (or ECS) installations. If your client doesn't have any deployment process, then you should suggest a possibility for them to implement.

A basic setup usually consists of and SCM (AWS codeCommit) a deployment manager (AWS codePipeline) and a deployment agent (AWS codeDeploy). There are drop in replacements for each of the 3 components here.

That being said, until you have some information that will allow you to access the file system (directly or indirectly), you cannot deploy to their server.